# Creating a reusable component and ensure that the template reference variable can be assigned to cdkDropList directive?

Tags: angular

https://codesandbox.io/s/hn-kanban-34mvt?file=/src/app/dragDrop/dragDrop.component.html:0-1308

How can I create a reusable component and ensure that I can assign the #newsList template reference variable to the cdkDropList directive and enable other components to reference newsList?

The issue is that the component is copy pasted 4 times, and I would like to build a component that can be reused to reuse the code and make it more maintainable, but the issue is that the template reference variable is different for each instance of the component, and I am not sure how I can pass the template reference variable name as a prop.

```
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>News </h2>

  <div class="example-list">
    <div
      cdkDropList
      #newsList="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="newsItems"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[topList, newsList, readLaterList, watchList]"
      class=""
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    >
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of newsItems" cdkDrag>
        <div>
          <strong>
            <a target="_blank" [href]="item.url">{{item.title}}</a> </strong
          >&nbsp;
          <a
            *ngIf="item.hostname"
            class="hn"
            target="_blank"
            [href]="'https://news.ycombinator.com/from?site='+item.hostname"
          >
            ({{item.hostname}})
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="secondRow">
          <span>by {{item.by}}&nbsp;</span>
          <span>Points: {{item.score}}&nbsp;</span>
          <span>{{foregoneTime(item.time)}} ago&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="thirdRow">
          <a target="_blank" [href]="item.url">Visit</a>&nbsp;
          <a
            class="hn"
            target="_blank"
            [href]="'https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id='+item.id"
            >{{item.descendants}} comments</a
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is one of the four component, and I want to avoid copy pasting and make the code as maintainable as possible, but I am confused as to how to ensure I can use various template reference variable names.

I also want to be able to pass the values of each to the [cdkDropListConnectedTo] attribute binding. Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, you can't reference a template directly within a child component. Instead, you can only use template references that exist within the component itself

However, you can attempt to pass the reference by using the Output decorator and EventEmitters

You can check [Component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) and [Sharing data between child and parent directives and components](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Here is an Example of your child component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-drop-list',
  templateUrl: './drop-list.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class DropListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('list', { static: false }) templateRef: any;
  @Output() templateRefReady = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input() otherListsTemplateRef: any[];

  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.templateRefReady.emit(this.templateRef);
  }

}
```

```html
<div cdkDropList
    #list="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="otherListsTemplateRef"
    ...
>
```

And your parent component:

```html
  <app-drop-list 
    (templateRefReady)="templateRefReady($event)"
    [otherListsTemplateRef]="otherListsTemplateRef">
  </app-drop-list>
```

```js
  templateRefReady(templateRef: any) {
    this.otherListsTemplateRef.push(templateRef);
  }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, how do you pass the otherListsTemplateRefs if they exist within the components themselves? @ViewChild('list', { static: false }) templateRef: any;

Comment: You can collect them in a variable stored in the parent component as you can see in the last snippet.

Comment: The templateRef, goes from child to parent with the templateRefReady event emitter, then you have all 4 templateRef stored in 'otherListsTemplateRef'.

Comment: Note that when you pass the reference of the templates with [otherListsTemplateRef]="otherListsTemplateRef", you want to filter out the template the represents that <app-drop-list>